# Simple button to send users info to an email address

Tags: hooks, ajax, emails, users

What would be the best route to create a button on a page that once it's clicked, it sends an email to the administrator. Basically we are using the profile percentage completion module, and when a user is at 100% I want to display a button to opt into a program (the program meaning, it sends us all of their info in their drupal account)

It seems very simple, but I can't wrap my head around this. I could definitely add the logic to where if the profile is 100%, it will display a button. It's just the button functionality that I don't know how to do. Would I write a ajax hook? create a custom module?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: The core Contact module might have some code you could grab out if it doesn't do what you want.  Examples of its use is here:  https://drupal.org/node/124129

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will help you.

In Drupal 7 you can use **[ctools](https://drupal.org/project/ctools)** for your requirement.

- Just create a **ctools link** after 100% of profile completeness

Steps

- Create link on 100% of profile completeness in the profile page

  `global $user;
  ctools_include('ajax'); // Include the CTools tools that we need.
  $entity_type = 'user';
  $bundle = 'user';
  if (module_exists('pcp')) {//check for 100% completeness
    $check_percentage = pcp_get_complete_percentage_data($entity_type, $bundle, $user);
    if (is_array($check_percentage)) {
      if ($check_percentage['current_percent'] == 100) {//100% of profile completed
        $mail_link = '';
        $mail_link = ctools_ajax_text_button(t("Send Mail"), "send_mail/nojs/$user->uid", t("Send Mail"));
        $link = "<div id='#send-mail-" . $user->uid . "'>"; //must have unique ID for replacement
        $link .= $mail_link;
        $link .= "";
      }
    }
    return $link;
  }`
- Create menu for callback

  `$items['send_mail/%ctools_js/%'] = array(
    'title' => '',
    'page callback' => 'send_mail_link',
    'page arguments' => array(1,2),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );....
   return $items;`
- Send mail callback

  `function send_mail_link($js, $uid) {
    // Include the CTools tools that we need.
    ctools_include('ajax');
    $output = '';
    if(isset($uid)){
       $output .= '<span class="mail-sent">Mail Sent</span>';//without link
      //Code for sending an email to the administrator
      if(/* mail sent */){
         drupal_set_message('mail sent');
      }
    }
    if ($js) {
      $commands = array();
      $commands[] = ajax_command_html("#send-mail-$uid", $output);
      print ajax_render($commands);
      exit;
    }
    else {
      return $output;
    }
  }`

Comment: Inizio, this is awesome! Let me play around with it, and I'll definitely let you know how it goes. Huge thanks!

Comment: Your welcome, enjoy :)

Comment: Inizio~ You don't understand how much that code helped me to learn how to ajax with drupal now. Seriously, I am now infatuated with it. I know you didn't add the email functionality, but with a couple of clicks to the API, and the examples plugin, I was able to achieve what I needed to achieve and more. Thank you so much for your thorough code, and for giving me more spark in Drupal. This is awesome!

Comment: +1 on the positiveness of this comment. IMO, GREAT posting by @inizio as an example for us to study! Thanks for the time.